# XeTeX and non-searchable ligatures, font with glyphs in the right Unicode range

Tags: fonts, xetex

Using XeTeX `3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)`, I'm trying to compile a document in Adobe Garamond Premier Pro but the ligatures are non-searchable in the output pdf.

Looking around it seems that the problem is common in XeTeX in different fonts, and they suggest that the problem is in the font because the ligatures glyphs are in the private use area (PUA) of the font.

I did the exercise with Adobe Garamond Pro (another font, don't confuse with Garamond Premier) and the ligatures are searchable.

**Adobe Garamond Pro** ligatures are searchable:

[image: Garamond]

**Adobe Garamond Premiere Pro** ligatures are non-searchable:

[image: Garamond Premier]

But both fonts have the ligatures in the same Unicode range, "Alphabetic Presentation Forms", which is the right place to put roman ligatures according to the standard.

**Adobe Garamond Pro** (With *searchable* ligatures):

[image: Adobe Garamond Pro ffi]

**Adobe Garamond Premier Pro** (With *non-searchable* ligatures):

[image: Adobe Garamond Premiere Pro ffi]

What is the status of this problem in XeTeX, is there any solution yet?

Edit:

Two examples:

- [With Adobe Garamond Pro](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cucho-share/Garamond.pdf) (ligatures searchable)
- [With Garamond Premier](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cucho-share/Premier.pdf) (ligatures non-searchable)

Below is the code to generate two files (each with a font):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}

The sufficient soufflè.

Adobe Garamond Pro

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know how this works in LuaLaTeX with Adobe Garamond Pro. It works because the ligatures have "searchable" ligature names such as f_i and f_f_i, regardless of whether or not they are in the PUA. I don't have the premier font. Are the ligature character names what I just wrote? If not, the issue is with the font (and there may be a TeX solution). But if they are, then the issue is with XeTeX.

Comment: How do you find the ligature names in a font?

Comment: FontForge (https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is useful for inspecting fonts, and for more than that.  In Adobe Garamond Premier Pro Opticals, the glyph is named `f_f_i`.

Comment: We need a minimal example, because I can’t reproduce the problem: with both `luatex` and `xetex`, the ligature is searchable.

Comment: How to find ligature names in a font (one way to do it): Install the free FontForge program. Open the font. Find the character in question. Right-click on it, use glyph info menu. See glyph name. If it is something like f_i or f_f_i (note the underscores) then the problem is with XeTeX and is an issue. But if the glyph name is something like uni3456, then the problem might be solvable by telling XeTeX what to do. Trick: In FontForge, use Encoding Compact to squeeze the font.

Comment: @Thérèse Actually, your comment leads me to believe that the problem is with the OP's code, not XeTeX or the font. Which PDF reader is the OP using? That might make a difference!

Comment: @Thérèse I added an example in the main question

Comment: @RobtA I am using Apple Preview as the PDF reader

Comment: Try another PDF reader, before you pin the problem on XeTeX or the font. Different PDF readers do different things. If you pick any PDF reader, and search for issues, you will find them. For example: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217532/disable-automatic-ligature-handling-in-pdf-preview-on-el-capitan

Comment: Still can’t reproduce the problem.  But with a recent `fontspec`, you don’t need to specify `Ligatures=TeX`, and `xltxtra` loads `fontspec`, so you don’t need both invocations of `\usepackage`.

Comment: @Thérèse and RobtA: I am installing Adobe Reader to test the output pdfs there

Comment: In both versions (Garamond and Garamond Premiere) the ligatures are searchable in Adobe Reader DC in a Mac OS X.